# Catching the response of the iFrame once receiving the response

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am posting a message to iFrame. The iFrame returns a response as a boolean. I need to catch the response when response arrives to the parent window from iFrame. My code is not working. Any idea onthis?

iFrame

```
<iframe id="opIFrame"  src="https://localhost:9443/oauth2/session" >

</iframe>
```

I'm sending a message to the iFrame periodically

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("opIFrame");

    setInterval(function(){

        message ='test' ;
        console.log('Request From RP: ' + message);

        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message,"https://localhost:9443/oauth2/session"); 

    },6000);
```

What I need to do is receive the response of the iFrame periodically. Up to now code is working. I added an eventlistener for iframe as below.

```
 iframe.addEventListener("message",test,false);
    function test(event){
        alert("test");
    }
```

But it is not firing periodically

Comment: Touffy, I added the code. Please suggest me an idea.

Comment: Hmm. So it does fire at least once or not at all? Any error?

Comment: No it is not firing at least once. No error appears too.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually very simple: you added the listener on the iframe (as an element of the parent window's DOM), instead of on the iframe's window. Just fix this and it works:

```
iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("message",test,false);
```

Comment: No Touffy it is not working. I tried that also. The event listener is not firing.

Comment: It worked when I tried, using exactly your code with just the modification above and a different value for the domain.

Comment: And if it's somehow related to the domain then you should see an error in the console telling you that you're not allowed to do something. The iframe's content is an HTML document, right?

Comment: In firefox im not seeing any error. But I just tested it in chrome. It gives "
(index):31 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://localhost:9443') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://localhost:8080')."

Comment: Aha. So… the iframe's contents are *not* what you set in the `<iframe src>` by the time you post the message to it?